# Ventilator/Respirator foley sound

Tags: sound-effects, foley

Trying to recreate this sound -

Tried a few things but had no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Have you managed to aurally break down the sound components? What can you hear?

Comment: What don't you like about the sound you included above? If you can help us understand why that recording isn't right then we have a better chance of getting you the answer you need.

Answer (score 1):

It has noise.
A square wave. (B Note)
A click in the low mids.
two click in the low

The person who recorded this video, added extra machine sound which is not necessary to add. Or you can just add another layer of noise and keep you EQ band at low mids.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the repeating pattern:
[image]

I created a flp file for you
https://www.file.io/download/LW13Ro6QcSzq
this is what it sounds like
https://voca.ro/1exteNFJuWQi

I didn't add a white noise as a fan noise in the background but it can be easily done